# Can you write using Facebook Graph API to a web site's Facebook Comment Module?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Assume a page, http://foo.com, has the Facebook comment social plugin http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) on it

Using the Graph API, I can retrieve the # of comments using the syntax https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://foo.com

I'm wondering if there is any way to contribute a comment through the Graph API for foo.com so it shows up in the comment plugin? (perhaps a POST with a user's access token as parameters?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a direct reply from Facebook about this and unfortunately there is no way to do this with the Graph API today.

Answer (score 0):

As for 31 July 2013, it is still not possible:

> This functionality was never and is not intended to be available.
>
> An error message has been added for this case: "Comments may not be
>   added to a comment plugin"

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164794086987157