# Post comments on facebook via android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am trying to publish a comment from my android app onto the links from facebook. I have successfully obtained the `{object-id}` from facebook via `GET Graph API`.

Below is the code I am using to post a comment:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "This is a test comment");

        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/"+facebookObjectId+"/comments",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "FACEBOOK GRAPH RESPONSE FOR POSTING COMMENTS: " + response);
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

But the response I am getting indicates that this can't be achieved that *Comments may not be added to a comment plugin*.

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) Comments may not be added to a comment plugin}}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can only comment on Facebook objects (such as posts or comments) – not “on” external URLs that use the comments plugin. // Facebook has a feature called Comment Mirroring in beta, that would achieve that.

Comment: Yeah, saw the Comment Mirroring bit but was curious if someone figured it out. One way is to use FQL but that's not a very elegant solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way to do this with the Graph API**  [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673821/can-you-write-using-facebook-graph-api-to-a-web-sites-facebook-comment-module)

> This functionality was never and is not intended to be available.
>
> An error message has been added for this case: "Comments may not be
>   added to a comment plugin"

you must check in [official facebook bugs list](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164794086987157), it will help you.

Inshort this functionality is not available till now, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22763421/3134215) for more